# Can I cover/wrap 6x6 post with plastic to protect them from rain during construction?

Tags: post

I built a patio cover and used 6x6 treated yellow pine posts. I'm going to build the deck in two months so the contractor left posts uncovered for now. Posts will be covered with hardi once floor is completed. I'm concerned that leaving the posts exposed to the rain will damage them. Should I cover them with plastic?

Answer (score 1):

If they are treated, they are probably okay. However, I have any easy fix; we had some 6x6 doug fir posts that were going to be out for a while, and we just put some 5 gallon buckets upside down on them. That keeps the end-grain dry - which is where it will absorb the most moisture - without sealing the end totally. Worked great.

Answer (score 0):

2 months will not hurt it. If anything plastic will trap moisture